# Running vite dev server inside docker container immediately exits

Tags: docker, vue.js, vite

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container) I want to run a vite dev server inside a docker container. The motivation is basically that I want to compose it with a backend server and distribute an easily repeatable environment to teammates.

However, when I run the container, it immediately exits with no logs other than

```
< docker run -p 8080:8080 hiking-weather-frontend

> hiking-weather-frontend@0.0.0 dev
> vite "--host"
```

The same happens when I switch to a container terminal and run `npm run dev` manually -- it immediately returns with the above message.

The Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npm i -g vite

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host"]
```

`vite.config.js`:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    watch: {
        usePolling: true
    }
    }
})
```

`package.json`

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    watch: {
        usePolling: true
    }
    }
})
```

Would be eternally grateful for any input. Thanks!

Comment: Why the --host if you don't provide a value ? npm run dev should be enough