# trying to dockerize my app, but something is wrong with frontend

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vuejs3

so im trying to dockerize my app but something is wrong with frontend.
i dont know exactly what because it seems like everything should work.

so first of all this is the output: (as you can see seems fine, i think lol).

```
docker-compose up
Starting backend ... done
Starting frontend ... done
Attaching to backend, frontend
backend     | 
backend     | > flexflix@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
backend     | > node dist/server.js
backend     | 
frontend    | 
frontend    | > flexflix@0.0.0 dev /app
frontend    | > npm run prettier && vite
frontend    | 
frontend    | 
frontend    | > flexflix@0.0.0 prettier /app
frontend    | > prettier --write src/
frontend    | 
frontend    | src/App.vue 214ms
frontend    | src/assets/base.css 14ms
frontend    | src/assets/main.css 6ms
frontend    | src/components/__tests__/HelloWorld.spec.ts 14ms
frontend    | src/components/HelloWorld.vue 47ms
frontend    | src/components/icons/IconCommunity.vue 5ms
frontend    | src/components/icons/IconDocumentation.vue 4ms
frontend    | src/components/icons/IconEcosystem.vue 3ms
frontend    | src/components/icons/IconSupport.vue 4ms
frontend    | src/components/icons/IconTooling.vue 4ms
frontend    | src/components/TheWelcome.vue 20ms
frontend    | src/components/WelcomeItem.vue 17ms
frontend    | src/main.ts 7ms
frontend    | src/router/index.ts 7ms
frontend    | src/stores/counter.ts 9ms
frontend    | src/views/AboutView.vue 5ms
frontend    | src/views/HomeView.vue 4ms
backend     | Connected to MongoDB Atlas
backend     | Server is running on port: 5000
frontend    | 
frontend    |   VITE v4.2.1  ready in 422 ms
frontend    | 
frontend    |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
frontend    |   ➜  Network: use --host to expose
```

but when im trying to reach http://localhost:3000/ the site is not reachable.

this is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    restart: always
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: always

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

and this is my client Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

last thing here is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "flexflix",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "build-only": "vite build",
        "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
        "prettier": "prettier --write src/",
        "dev": "npm run prettier && vite",
        "serve": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "pinia": "^2.0.32",
        "vue": "^3.2.47",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
        "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.0",
        "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
        "eslint": "^8.34.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
        "jsdom": "^21.1.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "prettier": "^2.8.4",
        "typescript": "~4.8.4",
        "vite": "^4.2.1",
        "vitest": "^0.29.1",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```

does anyone have an idea what could go wrong?
thank you guys for your help !

edit:
when i cd into client folder and type npm run dev it works fine !

i tried to dockerize my app but something is wrong..

Comment: Are you running into the same problem as [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container)?  The mention of only a `localhost` URL in the startup messages is a red flag, and that question seems to address this case.