# How do we correctly dockerize a Solid.js app?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, solid-js, solid-start

I want to run a *solid.js* project from a *Docker* container but I can't connect to the web-app via local host from my browser for some reason, but I was able to successfully do this with my *next.js* project so I figured the setup would be similar.

Here's the steps I followed. I initialize a new [solid-start](https://start.solidjs.com/getting-started/project-setup) project named *demo* via `npm init solid@latest demo` and make the following selections from the options provided

```
Which template do you want to use? --> bare
Server Side Rendering? --> yes
Use TypeScript? --> no
```

Then I navigate into the *demo* folder and hit `npm install` and start up the project with `npm run dev`, when I open `http://localhost:3000/` on my web browser the demo counter web-app runs fine.

Now the issue comes up when I want to introduce *Docker* into the mix. I create a **Dockerfile** inside my root directory with the following configuration

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

and also include the following **.dockerignore** file in the same folder

```
/node_modules
Dockerfile
.gitignore
.dockerignore
.solid
```

I then open docker desktop and execute the following command in my project folder `docker build -t demo-image:v0 .` to create a docker image of my project, which correctly shows up under my *Images* in docker desktop.

Then to create and run the corresponding docker container I execute the following command `docker run --name demo-container --rm -p 3000:3000 demo-image:v0` which again, correctly shows up under my *Containers* in docker desktop as a running instance.

Now when I go to `http://localhost:3000/` in my web browser, I get

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

strangely this time.

I've also tried older versions of alpine for the base image and various other parent images, but I get the same issue. The weird thing is that I follow a similar procedure when working with *next.js* projects and even tried manually doing each instruction inside the **Dockerfile** to validate my settings and it seems to work just fine. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if *solid.js* is not compatible with *Docker* just yet somehow, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Often dev servers bind to the localhost address 127.0.0.1, but in Docker this is a container-private localhost and the server isn't reachable from outside its own container.  [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container) is a different framework but a similar issue, for example.  Is there a config setting you need to change to make the dev server listen on 0.0.0.0 ("all interfaces")?

Comment: @DavidMaze might be onto something, try changing the line in package.json to `"dev": "vite --host"`, or adding `host: true` into the `server` section in vite.config.js