# Connection refused on react docker container with vite

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker, I'm trying to dockerize my react application.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

This is my vite-config file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    // host: true, Tested with both options
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

I am creating the image like this: `sudo docker build -t frontend .`

I am running the image like this: `sudo docker run -it frontend` 
When I run this command, this is what I get on my terminal

[image: Terminal]

When I open both options, Local and Network, I get the same error on my browser.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Docker can't read this PNG file at all.  It looks it might be a fairly routine Node/npm Dockerfile; how are you actually running it, is the container starting up, what URL are you trying to connect to, how is the application configured to listen to the network?  Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: A shot-in-the-dark guess from the question title might be [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container), which would cover one common combination of "vite", "Docker", and "connection refused".

Comment: I did both comments and I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not publishing the container port, it is now only available from inside the docker network. Using the `-p`-flag, you can publish it to the host machine and you should be able to access vite.

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 frontend
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run it from my computer before to publish it to docker-hub. This options WORKS! But I do not understand why, could you please explain it :)

Comment: `EXPOSE` does not automatically bind any ports between docker container and host. So when running the container you have to tell the docker engine, which port from the host machine (ie your computer) should be connected to a port of your running container.

Comment: @Tomas "publishing" here doesn't refer to publishing to docker-hub. Publishing a port is basically binding a port of container to that of the host machine. Refer docs - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish

Comment: Then, when I push it to Docker-Hub, should I keep running the command with the '-p' option?

Comment: Publishing to docker hub and publishing a port are two entirely unrelated concept, tho I understand they might be confusing. The `-p 3000:3000` part of the command only tells docker that port 3000 (the first number) on your machine should be forwarded to port 3000 (the second number) of your application

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot for that explanation, I will read more about it. Thanks to all!