# SvelteKit/Vite app in Docker container throws transform error when using lucide-svelte icons (but not inside docker?)

Tags: docker, vite, sveltekit

I'm writing a SvelteKit application that will run on Amazon ECS in a docker container, so for that reason I'm trying to run it locally in Docker during development as well.

Most everything works fine, with the exception of [lucide-svelte](https://lucide.dev/guide/packages/lucide-svelte).

When importing an icon for display in a page, I get this error message:

```
5:12:14 PM [vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to load url lucide-svelte/icons/home (resolved id: lucide-svelte/icons/home) in /app/src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte. Does the file exist?
5:12:24 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte: failed to import "lucide-svelte/icons/home"
|- Error: Cannot find module 'lucide-svelte/icons/home' imported from '/app/src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte'
    at nodeImport (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54756:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54663:30)
    at eval (/app/src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte:7:37)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54725:9)

Error: Cannot find module 'lucide-svelte/icons/home' imported from '/app/src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte'
    at nodeImport (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54756:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54663:30)
    at eval (/app/src/routes/(logged_in)/+layout.svelte:7:37)
    at async instantiateModule (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.1.4/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-jDlpJiMN.js:54725:9) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

The import in question:

```
import Home from 'lucide-svelte/icons/home';
```

I have other SvelteKit applications (including running in Docker) that use Lucide-svelte without issue, which makes me think this is some sort of configuration issue, but I can't find the problem. I thought maybe pnpm (and its heavy use of symlinks) might be to blame, but the other app also uses pnpm in the same way.

Something odd about this situation is that it only happens when running the application in Docker. If I run it on the host machine directly -- same code, no changes -- it shows the icon and doesn't throw the error.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-slim as base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
# delete node_modules copied from host system which could be M1 and cause arch conflicts in container build
RUN rm -rf /app/node_modules

FROM base as build
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm run build

FROM base AS prod-deps
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --prod --frozen-lockfile

FROM base
COPY --from=prod-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=prod-deps /app/package.json /app/package.json
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build
EXPOSE 5173
ENV PORT=5173
CMD [ "pnpm", "run", "start" ]
```

#### svelte.config.js

```js
import sequence from 'svelte-sequential-preprocessor';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: sequence([vitePreprocess({})]),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        paths: {
            //matches up with nginx reverse-proxy config
            base: '/admin/beta'
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

^ this differs from the working app in the base path -- the working app doesn't use this. But I removed it to test and that didn't fix the error.

#### vite.config.ts

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    // server object included because we were having the same problem as this person:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container
    server: {
        host: true,
        port: 5173
    },
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true
    }
}
```