# Haven't access to ports to conteinerized react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, deployment, vite

I can't get access to my container, but after it creation I have such message:

[image]

**I propose that this problem occures by bad ports configuration.**

#Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20.11.1-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

#docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    container_name: front-end-app
    image: app-dev
    build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    stdin_open: true
    env_file:
      - ./../.env
```

#package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
}
```

!updated
#vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), react()],
});
```

Comment: PS C:\Users\bynik> docker logs da911bc5d8c670ead5e62805f509454618c7a3e138e06d191acfc26c1a000077 > fantastic-points@0.0.0 dev > vite VITE v4.3.9 ready in 697 ms ➜ Local: localhost:5173 ➜ Network: use --host to expose
 There is no useful info.

Comment: That output suggests you need the setup from [running a vite dev server inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012970/running-a-vite-dev-server-inside-a-docker-container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you don't have the correct vite configuration. You should add a couple of lines to it to make it possible for vite to work in the docker

```js
    import { defineConfig } from "vite";
    import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
    import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
    
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [tsconfigPaths(), react()],
      server: {
        watch: {
          usePolling: true,
        },
        host: true,
        strictPort: true,
        port: 5173,
      }
    });
```

You can check the options here: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options